# XNA- How do I calculate the velocities of 2D circles after they collided with each other?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision, geometry

I have been Looking into making circles collide with each other and this is what I came up with so far:

```
foreach(Circle circle in circles)
    foreach(Circle circle2 in circles)
            {
                bool HasCollided = false;
                if(circle.ID != circle2.ID)
                {
                    double squareRoot =(Math.Pow(((int)circle.position.X - (int)circle2.position.X), 2) + Math.Pow((int)circle.position.Y - (int)circle2.position.Y, 2));
                    double distanceBetweenCentres = Math.Sqrt(squareRoot);
                    if(distanceBetweenCentres < (circle.radius + circle2.radius))HasCollided = true;                           
                    else if(distanceBetweenCentres> (circle.radius + circle2.radius)) HasCollided = false;
                    if(HasCollided == true)
                    {
                        double newVelX1 = ((circle.velocity.X * (circle.Mass - circle2.Mass) + (2 * circle2.Mass * circle2.velocity.X)) / (circle.Mass + circle2.Mass));
                        double newVelY1 = ((circle.velocity.Y * (circle.Mass - circle2.Mass) + (2 * circle2.Mass * circle2.velocity.Y)) / (circle.Mass + circle2.Mass));

                        double newVelX2 = ((circle2.velocity.X * (circle2.Mass - circle.Mass) + (2 * circle.Mass * circle.velocity.Y)) / (circle2.Mass + circle.Mass));
                        double newVelY2 = ((circle2.velocity.Y * (circle2.Mass - circle.Mass) + (2 * circle.Mass * circle.velocity.Y)) / (circle2.Mass + circle.Mass));

                        circle.velocity = new Vector2((int)newVelX1, (int)newVelY1);
                        circle2.velocity = new Vector2((int)newVelX2, (int)newVelY2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The code does work out when the circles are colliding, however the equation for the final velocity seems to make the circles either jump around the screen or slowly fall through each other, I tried finding a solution online but I couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions on what I could do to fix it?

new Code and GIF to show what it does:

```
 if(circle.ID < circle2.ID)
                {
                    double squareRoot =(Math.Pow(((int)circle.position.X - (int)circle2.position.X), 2) + Math.Pow((int)circle.position.Y - (int)circle2.position.Y, 2));
                    double distanceBetweenCentres = Math.Sqrt(squareRoot);
                    if(distanceBetweenCentres < (circle.radius + circle2.radius))HasCollided = true;                           
                    else if(distanceBetweenCentres> (circle.radius + circle2.radius)) HasCollided = false;
                    if(HasCollided == true)
                    {
                        double newVelX1 = ((circle.velocity.X * (circle.Mass - circle2.Mass) + (2 * circle2.Mass * circle2.velocity.X)) / (circle.Mass + circle2.Mass));
                        double newVelY1 = ((circle.velocity.Y * (circle.Mass - circle2.Mass) + (2 * circle2.Mass * circle2.velocity.Y)) / (circle.Mass + circle2.Mass));

                        double newVelX2 = ((circle2.velocity.X * (circle2.Mass - circle.Mass) + (2 * circle.Mass * circle.velocity.Y)) / (circle2.Mass + circle.Mass));
                        double newVelY2 = ((circle2.velocity.Y * (circle2.Mass - circle.Mass) + (2 * circle.Mass * circle.velocity.Y)) / (circle2.Mass + circle.Mass));

                        circle.velocity = new Vector2((float)newVelX1, (float)newVelY1);
                        circle2.velocity = new Vector2((float)newVelX2, (float)newVelY2);
                    }
                }
```

[image: New gif after changing code again]

Comment: Woops, lost the hashed part:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are jumping around there is a good chance that it is because they haven't separated by the time you do the next collision check. Try moving the circles from the impact point by their radius.

As an example using the first circle:

```
Cp = Cp + Normalize(Ip - Cp) * Cr
```

Where Ip is Impact Position, Cp is Circle Position and Cr is Circle Radius.
If it appears to be pushing the circle further into the collision, swap Ip and Cp before normalization.

EDIT: Came up with this after running the code myself:

Issue 1: 
In newVelX2 you are comparing CircleVelocity.Y instead of .X

Issue 2: 
You aren't checking for previously evaluated pairs. I solved this with the following code:
`

```
for (int c1Index = 0; c1Index < RigidBodies.Count; c1Index++)
 {
      for (int c2Index = c1Index + 1; c2Index < RigidBodies.Count; c2Index++)
      {
           HandleCollisions(RigidBodies[c1Index], RigidBodies[c2Index]);
      }
 }
```

`This prevents you from evaluating a pair twice. What I mean is, if following your code with 3 circles in the list:`

```
Outer Loop = Circle0
Inner Loop = Circle0 <-- C0 is skipped
Inner Loop = Circle1 <-- C0 and C1 pair evaluated
Inner Loop = Circle2 <-- C0 and C2 pair evaluated
Outer Loop = Circle1 
Inner Loop = Circle0 <-- C1 and C0 pair evaluated *PROBLEM: We already did this pair*
Inner Loop = Circle1 <-- C1 is skipped
Inner Loop = Circle2 <-- C1 and C2 pair evaluated
Outer Loop = Circle2 
Inner Loop = Circle0 <-- C2 and C0 pair evaluated *PROBLEM: We already did this pair*
Inner Loop = Circle1 <-- C2 and C1 pair evaluated *PROBLEM: We already did this pair*
Inner Loop = Circle2 <-- C2 is skipped
```

`

My code resolves this by having the inner loop begin at one past the currently evaluated circle, because anything before it has already been handled. Another option is to maintain a list of evaluated pairs, which obviously is more memory intensive, but completes the job.

For my demo I didn't have to separate the circles first. However, if you spawn the circles inside one another, they will be stuck like that. Therefore if you anticipate circles sometimes getting stuck together, you may want to keep the pseudo code from my original answer.

Additionally, the below code shows a more accurate response mechanism which I adapted from [this link](http://www.adambrookesprojects.co.uk/project/canvas-collision-elastic-collision-tutorial/):

```
 private void HandleCollisions(Circle Circle1, Circle Circle2)
    {
        if (!HaveCollided(Circle1, Circle2))
            return;

        Vector2D distance = Circle1.Position - Circle2.Position;
        Vector2D normalVector = distance.Normalize();

        Vector2D tangentVector = normalVector.GetTangentVector();

        float c1VelocityAlongNormal = VectorMath.CalculateDotProduct(normalVector, Circle1.Velocity);
        float c2VelocityAlongNormal = VectorMath.CalculateDotProduct(normalVector, Circle2.Velocity);

        float c1VelocityAlongTan = VectorMath.CalculateDotProduct(tangentVector, Circle1.Velocity);
        float c2VelocityAlongTan = VectorMath.CalculateDotProduct(tangentVector, Circle2.Velocity);

        float massSum = Circle1.Mass + Circle2.Mass;

        float c1Speed = (c1VelocityAlongNormal * (Circle1.Mass - Circle2.Mass) + (2.0f * Circle2.Mass * c2VelocityAlongNormal) / massSum);
        float c2Speed = (c2VelocityAlongNormal * (Circle1.Mass - Circle2.Mass) + (2.0f * Circle1.Mass * c1VelocityAlongNormal) / massSum);

        Vector2D c1FinalVelocity = normalVector * c1Speed;
        Vector2D c2FinalVelocity = normalVector * c2Speed;

        Vector2D c1Tangent = tangentVector * c1VelocityAlongTan;
        Vector2D c2Tangent = tangentVector * c2VelocityAlongTan;

        Circle1.Velocity = c1FinalVelocity + c1Tangent;
        Circle2.Velocity = c2FinalVelocity + c2Tangent;
    }

    **FROM VECTOR2D CLASS**
    class Vector2D
{
    public float X, Y;

    public Vector2D()
    {
        this.X = 0.0f;
        this.Y = 0.0f;
    }

    public Vector2D(float X, float Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public Vector2D(Vector2D vectorToCopy)
    {
        this.X = vectorToCopy.X;
        this.Y = vectorToCopy.Y;
    }

    public float CalculateMagnitudeSquared()
    {
        return (this.X * this.X) + (this.Y * this.Y);
    }

    public float CalculateMagnitude()
    {
        return (float)Math.Sqrt((this.X * this.X) + (this.Y * this.Y));
    }

    public Vector2D GetTangentVector()
    {
        return new Vector2D(-this.Y, this.X).Normalize();
    }

    public Vector2D Normalize()
    {
        return new Vector2D(this / CalculateMagnitude());
    }

    public static Vector2D operator+(Vector2D thisVector, Vector2D otherVector)
    {
        return new Vector2D(thisVector.X + otherVector.X, thisVector.Y + otherVector.Y);
    }

    public static Vector2D operator-(Vector2D thisVector, Vector2D otherVector)
    {
        return new Vector2D(thisVector.X - otherVector.X, thisVector.Y - otherVector.Y);
    }

    public static Vector2D operator*(Vector2D thisVector, Vector2D otherVector)
    {
        return new Vector2D(thisVector.X * otherVector.X, thisVector.Y * otherVector.Y);
    }

    public static Vector2D operator*(Vector2D thisVector, float scalar)
    {
        return new Vector2D(thisVector.X * scalar, thisVector.Y * scalar);
    }

    public static Vector2D operator/(Vector2D thisVector, Vector2D otherVector)
    {
        return new Vector2D(thisVector.X / otherVector.X, thisVector.Y / otherVector.Y);
    }

    public static Vector2D operator/(Vector2D thisVector, float scalar)
    {
        return new Vector2D(thisVector.X / scalar, thisVector.Y / scalar);
    }
}
```

This isn't the neatest code... just threw it together to test this stuff.

Any further issues, let me know

Comment: I've been messing around with it, but it doesn't seem to be working, how would I go about normalizing it?

Comment: Ip and Cp are both vectors. So just normal vector normalization.

X = X/magnitude   Y = Y/magnitude   Z=Z/magnitude

Comment: The circles are still jumping around, they are definitely colliding, however they just keep jumping off of each other when they touch

Comment: Could you post a video demonstrating it?

Comment: I've added a gif above ^

Comment: Is that after adding the code from my answer, or was that how it was beforehand? I'm assuming the former, as I don't see any position-setting code in your example

Comment: They just pass through each other without the code, but when I added the new code they seem to do the right thing but the scale seems to be off

Comment: I think we are on the right track... after slowing your gif down with http://ezgif.com, it looks like it is mostly correcting it properly. The first case it gets separated, and then pushed back up from being below the screen edge. The second time is definitely problematic.
How are you calculating Impact Point? I'm thinking that might be where the problem lies.

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to finetune the equation, I'll post what I have right now so you can have a look through it

Comment: You don't need sin or cosin for this. 
To get the Impact Point you can do 
    `(C1 + C2) * 0.5f`
Where C1 and C2 are the respective positions of the circles. And you would do it with both circles.
Which reminds me, how do you handle iterating through circles? Because another reason you may have these problems are double evaluating pairs of circles. 
What I mean is you do C1 vs C2, then you do C2 vs C1. Each pair should only be evaluated once.

Comment: I added my new code above^ they should only evaluate each pair once because I added the if(circle.ID < circle2.ID), there is also a gif underneath of how it's looking now. It seems to be working a lot better, however It still doesn't work very well if more circles are added, also the direction of travel seems to be random

Comment: I'm going to create a demo project in a couple hours to see if I can replicate it. That first one doesn't look too bad. It seems like the ones afterwards may not be being evaluated (which I don't think is the case because they stop on collision), a divide by zero error on the velocity, or velocity somehow becoming 0.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to look at it yet, if you could replicate it that would be a big help, thank you

Comment: Updated my answer with what I believe will fix it all for you.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it out in a few hours, really appreciate the help